# Any exploratory work with AI and Deep learning for First Post Review?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Doing First Post Review is so tedious, is there any project to use trendy Deep Learning and AI to pre-filter this list?

Comment: Well, my NI has some troubles to understand your question, could you please elaborate? There is a https://cs.stackexchange.com and an https://ai.stackexchange.com .

Comment: To the folks wanting to close this question:  this is *still* a legitimate question to pose.  Not liking it doesn't warrant immediate closure of it.

Comment: @Makoto I think that they're mistaking it for a programming question belonging on the main site.

Comment: There are some, AFAIK, regex-level stuff (so not AI) which prevents people from posting too much code or using bad titles, for example, so that's attempting to at least grab some low-hanging fruit for the root this problem.

Comment: We already have "mostly code" and "unformatted code" warning. Probably others too. How SE implements it (is it based on AI), I don't know. Also, SmokeDetector.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is kinda where real people have to help out.

Don't feel obligated to do it if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, there are people who actually *enjoy* reviewing those. There's quite enough of them as-is, so if you think it's too tedious you can just leave it to them.

There are already a number of manually-programmed heuristics that flag posts as VLQ, but they still need human interaction nonetheless.

Final thoughts: with 16,000,000+ questions, and countless more deleted, Stack Overflow would be a *great* source of training data for CBLSTM.

Comment: My feeling is that First Code Review could  be more enjoyable if the 20% of total garbage questions were already stripped off.  Why ask human to do this task ? ( cutting the so obvious questions that gonna be closed in 2min ?) . Is it because people here don`t trust  algorithm and machines ? Or  maybe because some people have a feeling of power when bashing a noob ?

Answer (score -4):

If you review 1000 first-post (and late-answers), you get a golden badge.

Having many golden badges doesn't give any privileges, but it has some positive side-effects:

- The count of your moderation badges is a well-visible property of the candidates on the mod elections. If you ever want to nominate on an election, it is highly adviced to collect the golden badge for all the review queues.
- And having many golden badges has a positive psychological effect against the wonderful people trying to suppress and harm anything what they can see on the sites.

Furthermore, the first-post (and late-answer) review queues are mostly very simple decisions, and access to these queues is the simplest (requires only 500 on graduated sites).

On these reasons, typically the first-post and particularly the late-answer queues are nearly empty on most SE sites. Getting the golden badge for late-answers is one of the hardest to collect.

*The important thing in these queues, that they give some "extra attention" to the new users. Typically, beginners are ignored or nearly ignored on the sites, and all the reaction what they get is coming in the form of negative votes (down, close, del). However, to attract a newbie in the system, he needs human interaction. This is one of the few things, what the SE knows from its stats and uses this info to tune the sites. Surprisingly, the newbies aren't really upset by downs, not even by closures. What expels a newbie, if they don't get human interaction: most ideally, an answer, but also comments and edits are attracting them a lot.*

On these reasons, although it is an acceptable "solution" for a first-post or review problem is to vote it up or down, if you want to do any positive for the system, then *do also something, what only a human can do*: fix his post by an edit, comment it, flag it (note: flagging means typically a VLQ flag, it puts their question into the VLQ queue, where they will likely get at least an automatic comment).

I remember as I was a rep1 user. I didn't know from the system anything, but I've seen as I've got positive comments to my first posts, sometimes ups, sometimes downs (I ignored them), *they've even fixed my English*, for free! This all was simply awesome! Although I didn't know at the time, it is just the result of the first-post queue.

Later I've faced also its negative side: the hairsplitting piranhas, the organized hird downvoters, the closures on crap reasons, the unexplainable limitations of the system, but the important is: *it happened already after the strongly positive first impression*.

If I get these in the opposite order, I had likely gone away and never come back.

*Working on the FP/LA is a way to give some better to other newbies between 1-50, what you've got from the System between 50-500.*

I typically try to advice the SE, to use more AI / data mining to tune their site, I think they are too strongly focused on the community management. It seems their business model is that instead of writing AI for themselves, rather they try to catalize us to become their AI. Mainly it works well, but not always (see, for example, the excess mass of the VtC queue on the SO, which was rather re-categorized as "not a problem", instead of being fixed by a structural development).

On these reasons, I think these queues are the few ones where the human interaction should be catalyzed and not an AI should be developed. But, in general, the SE should use *much more* data minig, AI and soft methods as they are doing now.