# Was the daily review cap recently increased for some queues?

Tags: support, review-queues

I have a pretty distinct memory of the [First answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers), [First questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions), [Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) and [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) review queues being capped at 20 to 40 reviews per day.

Now they are all capped at 40, with the exception of First questions which is capped at 60.

I can’t seem to find any meta post about it. Is it a new change? Is it something that only changed for me because I passed some rep bar or achieved a certain medal? Or am I just remembering wrong?

Comment: First Questions was at 60 for a while before and then went back to 40. It seems to have gone back to 60 roughly when the queue size got to 12k. I haven't seen any announcement.

Comment: Related/partial(?) dupe: [The backlog of reviews in the First questions review queue is increasing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411502/2821954): "*In addition to the above changes, when there are a lot of items in the queue, the max number of reviews per day per user has been doubled for First questions, from 40 to <s>80</s> 60 (we originally moved it to 80, which led to the queue size decreasing at a rate that was a bit high, so moving it down to 60).*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Stack Overflow only, when a review queue reaches 150 items, the limit per user changes to 40 instead of 20. That's why, on some days, the [top reviewers today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats) are at 20, and others at 40.

When the items in the queue increases a lot ([First answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/stats) now reaches 500 each day, whereas before it rarely reached 200...), all queues are at 40. But that’s the expected behavior.

For the [First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/stats) queue, that's a little bit different:

A few month ago, I posted [The backlog of reviews in the First questions review queue is increasing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411502/10952503), because we reached 10k items in the queue. Some changes have been made and they have been useful because the backlog was decreasing. Some weeks ago, Stack Overflow's staff removed the special behavior that enabled the limit on the First Questions review queue to increase to 60 at the 150 item threshold ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411502/the-backlog-of-reviews-in-the-first-questions-review-queue-is-increasing#comment874407_412063)).

As it now exceeds 10k (and now, 14k), they made the decision to revert it back.

I hope they will do something in the long-term to reduce the amount of First Questions, because changing from 40 to 60 and then back again every two months is not—for me—a good solution. I made [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413441/10952503) (10k+ link) to propose a solution, and there are propositions that have been made to fix this ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260039/12299000), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280757/12299000), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374685/12299000), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390146/12299000), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320877/12299000), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256531/12299000), [7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258396/12299000)).

Comment: Yes it's all the process of gathering statistics. Without statistics you can't pinpoint an actual solution. It's all fun and games to propose solutions and pretend it'll end world hunger but it is then left up to the actual engineers to deal with butterfly effects and fallout.

Comment: Note that none of those solutions is practical for actually dealing with the size of the queue, since none target the drivel of meh questions we get every day. [Reverting the queue to the single click action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411507/792066) on the other hand had demonstrated to make reviewing less annoying.

Comment: @Gimby Propose solution with explaination of how it can improve does force engineers to use it. Those questions aren't accepted or refused, and SO can refuse question to don't have "butterfly effect" of bad proposal. Also, Braiam, they are "long-term" solution and not only to reduce the amount of review right now (but not increase it so much)

Comment: *"Propose solution with explaination of how it can improve does force engineers to use it."* - mmmm no, not in the slightest. Fact of the matter is that SO does not have to listen to anything posted on meta and the proof keeps building that they really do not look at feature requests anymore (perhaps if there wouldn't be so many of them...). Whatever changes are done to the site come from a higher order now. If you've found a good one they'll fix a bug though.

Comment: Oups, I would like to tell that it doesn't not force, not the opposite...

Comment: Aside, I want to reinforce just how unusual it’s been to see _First Answers_ consistently exceeding 400 over the last few days. I’m not certain if that’s because of an increase in answers, a decrease in reviewers, or perhaps an indirect effect of the _First Questions_ rules being adjusted (e.g., reviewers focusing limited attention on 60 First questions instead of 40 first answers). Regardless, it’s unprecedented in the (admittedly short) history of the queue.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyCaney for the edit, the message of the edit (<3) and I think it's because there is less reviewers than before (less at 40, and for example Ouflak & ZygD don't make them each days now)